# Separate two inputs C++

Tags: c++

I have made a quiz helper, but, as I want it for you to be able to input a new question without starting it, I made a do/while loop. The first run goes fine. When it asks you if you want to input another question, if you choose y, it runs the main program too at the same time, and the program registers y as a question. How do I separate this?Code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Quiz.h"
#include "Quiz2.h"

char choice;

int main()
{
          do{
          quiz();
          std::cout << "Da li zelite da vam odgovorim na jos jedno pitanje?(y/n)" << std::endl;

          std::cin >> choice;
          } while(choice != 'n');
}
```

The first header file just includes the function to find words:

```
#ifndef QUIZ_H_INCLUDED
#define QUIZ_H_INCLUDED

bool contains_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word)
{
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = sentence.substr(pos).find(word)) != std::string::npos) {
                if (!(isalpha(sentence[pos - 1])) || !(isalpha(sentence[pos + word.size() + 1])))
                        return true;
        }

        return false;
}

#endif
```

And the other one contains the real code, it is partially in Serbian:

```
#ifndef QUIZ2_H_INCLUDED
#define QUIZ2_H_INCLUDED
int quiz()
{
        std::string sentence;
        std::cout << "Ukucajte pitanje ili kljucne reci: " << std::flush;
        std::getline(std::cin, sentence);

        std::string word ("Belgija");
        std::string word2 ("regija");
        std::string word3 ("Kanada");
        std::string word4 ("teritorija");
        std::string word5 ("Holandija");
        std::string word6 ("delova");

        if (contains_word(sentence, word) && contains_word(sentence, word2))
                std::cout << "Odgovor je 3 regije." << std::endl;
        else if (contains_word(sentence, word3) && contains_word(sentence, word4))
                std::cout << "Odgovor je 3 teritorije." << std::endl;
        else if (contains_word(sentence, word5) && contains_word(sentence, word6))
                std::cout << "Odgovor je 3 dela." << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Nisam mogao pronaci odgovor na to pitanje!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}



#endif
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is suitable for Programmers; this looks more like a Stack Overflow question. I heard someone give a shortcut to know where to post: If your question involves tons of code, it probably belongs in SO. Programmers is more for abstract problems and questions unrelated to specific code. I'm sure someone will disagree with that, but Ive gotten scolded less since I followed that.

Comment: @CrAzYPiLoT Welcome to StackOverflow. To make this question easier to answer, please modify the code sample to be "Minimal, complete, verifiable". See help at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `pos + word.size() + 1` buffer overflow example

Comment: @CrAzYPiLoT also please do not write function code in header files. In header file you should have header, for example `bool contains_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word);`. Move function implementation to a .cpp file.

Comment: As @self pointed out, you shouldn't get value of `sentence[pos + word.size() + 1]` if it is possible for the word to be at the very end of sentence (subscript past the end of array). The same for `sentence[pos - 1]` - what if pos is 0? You get some random stuff before the string. You have to rework the condition also - certainly `if( !(...) || !(...) )` is not what you wanted to test. Probably something like `if( (pos == 0 || ...) && (pos+word.size() == sentence.size() || ... ) )`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a newline character after a choice, so just add `cin.ignore`:

```
std::cin >> choice;
std::cin.ignore();
```

It ignores one character from input.

### Alternative solution

Alternatively, you could discard all empty lines in `quiz()` function - substitute

```
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
```

with

```
do {
    std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
} while( sentence.empty() );
```

### Other issue with the code

The `contains_word` function should be corrected. You shouldn't get value of `sentence[pos + word.size() + 1]` if it is possible for the word to be at the very end of sentence (subscript past the end of array).

Similar error in `sentence[pos - 1]` - what if pos is 0? You get some random stuff before the string.

You have to rework the condition also - certainly `if( !(...) || !(...) )` is not what you wanted.

Should be something like this:

```
bool contains_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = sentence.substr(pos).find(word)) != std::string::npos) {
        if( (pos == 0 || isalpha(sentence[pos - 1])) && 
            (pos + word.size() == sentence.size() || isalpha(sentence[pos + word.size()])) )
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`getline()` and `cin` don't play well together. After a `cin` operation there is typically a newline left in the input stream that the `getline` reads and immediately concludes it is done. You can "solve" the problem by calling `getline` twice and ignoring the first result. However note that this only happens AFTER a call to `cin`, so the first time thru you should NOT use `getline` twice. This is why I say they "don't play well together".